# Alternatives to a sliding switch and relay?

Tags: transistors, switches, relay, thyristor

There is a sliding switch on my board to select two different cases. A key like this:

[image: From sparkfun.com]
*From sparkfun.com*

You know its equivalent schamtic is as below:

[image: From sparkfun.com]
*From sparkfun.com*

I am designing another board to control some devices including this one. I want to replace this sliding key with an controllable electronic device. The first thing which crossed my mind was relays. However, They seem to be bulky and have over current capacity. Are there any other electronic devices to implement this sliding key in a smaller and more proper way?

**Edit based on comments:**
There are 11 devices which could be categorized as three groups:
1. two fans: I dealt with it by using relay. Yet I am curious to know if there is any other way.
2. eight devices are low level logic signal (not audio or data stream ones and they are quite slow).
3. one device needs to be handled with both switch and software.

Comment: What do you mean with a controllable electronic device? That the 'manual'  switch is replaced by a (software) controlled electronic device? Or that it is a manual switch that 'also' can be controlled electronically? In the first case, you probably need some kind of (de)multiplexer IC.

Comment: You need to supply more information.  What does the switch control?  Is it power (select a power source or destination) or is it a low-level signal such as audio or a digital data stream?  How much ON resistance can your circuit handle?

Comment: @ Michel Keijzers only one device need to be handle by two manual and software control. So the solution should consider this case. Thanks.

Comment: @ Dwayne Reid, you are right. I am editing my question.

Comment: This is too broad to be answered. If it is AC then stick with relays. If it is power, perhaps a MOSFET or BJT. If it is signals, analog switches. And so on. Most importantly you'd need to know the amount of current and the nature of the signal.

Comment: @lundin only number 2 (those eight devices) is main question. I wrote others to be accurate! seems not to reach my goal! how to use transistors to have a SPDT key? I need to connect a common pin either to pin A or in B.

Answer (score 3):

You can get small surface mount SPDT switches, such as [this one](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74lvc1g3157.pdf) by Texas Instruments. It is essentially just a 2:1 multiplexer.

However, it isn't quite that simple. You will need to find out a few more things about what will be required of the switch, such as how fast do you need it to switch, what current will be going through it, is it signal/power etc.

Using a parametric search like the one on sites like Digikey can help you select the parameters that you need, and you can then look through the list of devices to see which ones will suit your needs.

But to answer your question, yes. Such devices do indeed exist.